# Can't add data to Firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm new to React Native/Expo. I'm trying to integrate Firebase Firestore with my app so I can persist some data.

I've created a file `firebase.js` in a folder called `config`:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // All the relevant firebase config data is here, removed for this post
};

// Initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore();
} else {
  const app = firebase.app().firestore();
}
```

In my `App.js`, I'm trying to save the latitude and longitude of the device to Firestore:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import firebase from "./config/firebase";

import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  const add = (x, y) => {
    if (x === null || x === "" || y === null || y === "") {
      return false;
    }

    firebase.collection("users")
      .doc(1)
      .set({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);

    add(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Fairly straightforward stuff.

However, when I run this, I get an error:

> Component Exception
>
> _firebase.default.collection is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.collection("users")`, '_firebase.default.collection' is undefined)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing what you export as `firestore` from `./config/firebase`, but it must be what you're expecting.

According to the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart), you want to be doing something along these lines:

```
var db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection("users").doc //etc
```

So, in this scenario, you'd want to export `db` as `firestore` in your `config/firebase/`

Note that this is for version 8 of the web API, which I'm assuming you're using based on your code checking `firebase.apps.length`. If you're using version 9, you'll need to update your code for the new API.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you’re importing libraries as the example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize). Apparently, you’re using version 9 of the SDK (modular), therefore, the way of managing data is different. You can compare the differences [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#example_1_refactoring_an_function).

As in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document), version 8 was made as follows:

```js
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
```

In version 9, it should be done this way:

```js
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document in collection "cities"
await setDoc(doc(db, "cities", "LA"), {
  name: "Los Angeles",
  state: "CA",
  country: "USA"
});
```

You should also [check the firestore version you are running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53615059/13171940) and [set up your environment accordingly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#set_up_your_development_environment).

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  // All the relevant firebase config data is here, removed for this post
};

// Initialize Firebase
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore();
export default app;
} else {
  const app = firebase.app().firestore();
export default app;
}
```

Before you use import firebase from "./config/firebase"; you need to export Default; so that the imported variable "firebase" will be either "firebase.app().firestore();" or "firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore()"

you can then firebase.collection("users") .doc(1) .set({ x: x, y: y }); because the variable firebase is actually firestore

Comment: Can you add a few words to explain how your code answers the OP's question?

Comment: Before you use import firebase from "./config/firebase";
you need to export Default; 
so that the imported variable "firebase" will be  either "firebase.app().firestore();" or "firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig).firestore()"

Comment: you can then

  firebase.collection("users")
      .doc(1)
      .set({
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
because the variable firebase is actually firestore

Comment: Please [edit] your post instead of commenting.